# How to pick path of file from System properties in jmeter CSV Data Set Config

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am trying to use CSV Data Set Config to get some data from csv file to be used in jmeter script but i don't want to hardcode the file path as it will be changing according to the test environment. Is there a way i can pick this path from System properties i.e some export set in my bashrc file.

Export in my bashrc :

```
export NIMBUS4_PERFORMANCE_TEST_REPO=/Users/rahul/Documents/verecloud/performancetest/data/user.csv
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following workaround:

Change "Filename" setting of the CSV Data Set Config to following:

```
${__BeanShell(System.getenv().get("NIMBUS4_PERFORMANCE_TEST_REPO"))}
```

[image: Beanshell CSV Path]

Where:

- [System.getenv()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) - method which provides access to underlying operating system environment variables
- [__Beanshell()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) - JMeter built-in function which allows executing of arbitrary [Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) code

Comment: Perfectly answers my requirement .. appreciate the help !! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a **softlink** at some static path. For example,

say we have created a soft link to `/user/data/csvs` folder.
You are in say `~/Documents` , there run below

> ln -s /user/data/csvs

Now we can access it in the jmeter and you will also have the flexibility to modify the softlink to point to some other location too.

Only constraint i see is the pointed directory name shouldn't change.

Hope this will help!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have just `users.csv` if the file is in the `same folder as the .jmx` itself;
2. You can have `${location}\users.csv`

   And in your UserDefinedVariables you'll have
   [image]

and in non-gui mode you'll refer as

```
%RUNNER_HOME%\Test.jmx -Jloc=%RUNNER_HOME%\users.csv -Jusers=100 -Jloop=1 -Jrampup=5
```